# How to store audio files and their metadata (names) so that they can be easily localized?

Tags: android, localization, assets, android-resources, android-assets

I need to store audio files and their metadata (names). There was an idea to just take the name from the file name, but I ran into a localization problem.

It would be possible to set a string resource pointing, depending on the locale, to different subdirectories in assets, but for this it would be necessary save copies of audio files for each language, so this is not an option.

Another way is to create subfolders in the assets folder for each locale, where text files containing localized metadata and links to audio resources.

Help find the best option.

Comment: On the first line you are still not telling where you wanna save files. You should mention assets there.

Comment: You are not telling how meta data should be stored.

Comment: @blackapps This is done in order to show that it is not necessary for me to use assets, and so that I can be offered the best place to do this. But it seems to me that there is no other place. Should I specify assets explicitly?

Comment: You can only deliver files with your app in assets or res/raw. Its to you.